# How to call Done button of mpmovieplayer without touch or click of Done button on screen in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone

How to call Done button of `mpmovieplayer` without touch or click of Done button on screen in ios ?
I mean how to access or call Done button manually after declare of notification.
like this....

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
- (void)willExitFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification{
    NSLog(@"willExitFullscreen");}
```

so here how to call `exitedFullscreen`. ?

Comment: Done button simply stop and dismiss mpmovieplayercontroller. You can do the same in custom method as well.